# Netbeans Maven Error: javac: invalid target release: 1.7

Tags: netbeans, maven, java

I am trying to build an existing maven project on a fresh install of the latest netbeans but am getting the following error, any help is much appreciated:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project com.rory.ngp.test: Compilation failure
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid target release: 1.7
```

I think it has something to do with paths but am not sure exactly. Here is the contents of my `/usr/lib/jvm directory;`

```
bash-4.1$ pwd
/usr/lib/jvm
bash-4.1$ ls   
java                               java-openjdk   jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0             jre            jre-gcj
java-1.6.0                         jre-1.5.0      jre-openjdk
java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64  jre-1.5.0-gcj
java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64          jre-1.6.0
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks oers, you were right.

I needed to install JDK 1.7/Java 7, and then edit the netbeans config file in the netbeans install directory /etc/netbeans.conf to point to where I installed the new version of Java:

```
    # Default location of JDK, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir>:
    netbeans_jdkhome="/users/rory/Documents/jdk1.7.0_02"
```

Comment: Since I had the same problem with IntelliJ: The solution there is to set the JRE version in the Maven|Runner project settings.

Comment: It seems to be a strange fact that if you install a new jdk when Netbeans is already installed, you need to manipulate the netbeans_jdkhome as describe here. Netbeans should be able to detect which is the latest jdk and use that if what the netbeans_jdkhome points to is not found. This must be a bug in Netbeans from the days of old.

Answer (score 9):

Add the following to your pom under build and plugins it should target 1.6

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I changed it I now get the error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)

Comment: @Rory if you need java 1.7 language features then you have to install a java 1.7 jdk on your machine

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
       <compilerArguments>
            <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
       </compilerArguments>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If Platform or Source/Binary Format in project properties is not same with this configuration it gives error